# requirejs load js but not work - magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, requirejs

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'gworks/jquery':'Vendor_Module/js/jquery.min'           
        },

    }
};
```

In template file, I called like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['gworks/jquery'],function($) {
    $(window).load(function () {
         alert('load from external jquery');
    });
});
</script>
```

In browser **net** tab above added js loaded **[200 ok]**

`http://domainame/pub/static/frontend/Vendor/theme/en_US/Vendor_Module/js/jquery.min.js`

but it still throw error in browser console like `TypeError: $ is not a function` and alert also does not come.

I am not familiar in requirejs so I doubted myself anything am I missing here?

Comment: please let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep below syntax in requirejs-config.js file

```
   var config = {
        paths: {            
                'gworks/jquery':"Vendor_Module/js/jquery.min" ,
            },   
        shim: {
            'gworks/jquery': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
        }
    };
```

In script,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery','gworks/jquery'],function($) {
    $(window).load(function () {
         alert('load from external jquery');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Remove var and check in frontend

Comment: thanks @Rakesh still it throws `$ is not a function`

Comment: you can just deploy run command, remove var folder and clear browser cache

Comment: yes I have done clear redis cache, remove var/*, static content deploy, clear browser cache.

Comment: i have update answer, you have missing jquery in script in template, require(['jquery','gworks/jquery']

Comment: no @rakesh that is my idea I am trying to use my `external jquery[gworks/jquery]` instead of default one. does it make sense?

Comment: ['jquery'] is the essential for all the inclusion of external js?